# How to access Selenium devTools from different Browsers?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How can i use Selenium DevTools with Grid and different browsers?

As I understand that CDP is only for Chrome. How can I run the same test case using CDP or DevTools on Firefox?

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
DevTools devTools = driver.getDevTools();   <---- Cannot resolve method 'getDevTools' in 'WebDriver'
driver.get("https://todomvc.com/");
```